# Reproducing Kernel of subspace of $L^2(0,1)$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

#### Definition of the problem

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space which consists of functions, defined on a set $S$. Let $k:S\times S \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ is our reproducing kernel for $\mathcal{H}$.
Now, let $\mathcal{H}$ be the two-dimensional subspace of $L^2(0,1)$, consisting of the functions $f(t)=a+bt,\ a,b\in \mathbb{K}$. I am asked to find the reproducing kernel for $\mathcal{H}$.

#### My efforts

I have to show that $f(t)=\left\langle f,k_{t}\right\rangle $.
Given that $f(t)=a+bt$, we have to find $k_t$ such that $a+bt= \left\langle a+bt,k_{t}\right\rangle$. And in $L^2(0,1)$, we know that $\left\langle f,k_{t}\right\rangle =\int f\left(t\right)\overline{k_{t}}dt=f\left(t\right)$.

#### My question

How could I find from there the reproducing kernel of $\mathcal H$? Should I integrate over $dt$, and between $(0,1)$ ?

Thank you, Franck!

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb K$ is either $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. I think in some other books, it can also be denoted by $\mathbb F$. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the formula $a+bt= \left\langle a+bt,k_{t}\right\rangle$ is a mess: two different variables are denoted by the same letter $t$. It should be $a+bt= \int_0^1 (a+bs)\overline{k_{t}(s)}\,ds$. Now if this is to hold for all $a$ and for all $b$, then the coefficients of $a$ and $b$ must be the same on both sides. 
$1=\int_0^1 \overline{k_{t}(s)}\,ds$ and $t=\int_0^1 s\overline{k_{t}(s)}\,ds$. This gives you two equations for two unknowns in $k_t(s)=\alpha_t+\beta_t s$.

Comment: Thank you Leonid.

For the record, I obtain $k_{t}(s)=4-6\overline{t}+\left(12\overline{t}-6\right)s$.

Comment: @FranckStudiesCommEng Since $t$ and $s$ belong to $[0,1]$, the complex conjugate is unnecessary. In a more symmetric form, $k_t(s)=4-6(t+s)+12ts$. Notice that $k_t(s)=k_s(t)$, and this is not a coincidence.